# extract color objects using spatial and frequency domain filtering

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, histogram, frequency-analysis

This is the image I am having. I am trying to extract the yellow stars alone from this image using spatial and frequency domain filters. Can anybody suggest me a good method to do it, that would be robust as well? I am trying to use histogram in spatial domain, to see some values, so that I can threshold later. Any other robust idea is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Convert to HSV (with `rgb2hsv` or similar) and apply two thresholds in the H component to isolate the desired range of yellow colours?

Comment: Does it necessarily need to be with filters? @LuisMendo above makes a good point with the threshold operation, and it would be very straightforward. If you want to make it a bit more flexible and a lot more complicated, K-Means Segmentation or Fuzzy C-Means Segmentation, to do the same. That would only be necessarily if you had a broad number of similarly colored triangles (ie: orange, yellow, light red, etc).

Comment: Also, if you do need help with the thresholding operation (doubtful, but possible) I can point you to some matlab examples for black and white which would be easy to extend to RGB. You would just have to specify a unique range for each of the three color values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input guys. I am trying to have a repository of various methos. I will update once I have tried a few.